# Getting consecutive login with Dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

Trying to figure out how to track consecutive logins but I'm having trouble with getting the correct output with Dplyr

Code:

```
Login       User 
2015-01-05   A
2015-01-06   A
2015-01-07   A
2015-01-05   B
2015-01-07   B
2015-01-05   C
2015-01-10   C
```

Expected result (Assuming 2015-01-05 is Day 0):

```
User  One_day  Two_day 
A      Yes      Yes
B      No       Yes
C      No       No
```

My attempt:

```
df %>%
    group_by(User) %>%
    mutate( 
        One_day = ifelse(Login == "2015-01-05" & Login == "2015-01-06", "Yes", "No"),
        Two_day = ifelse(Login == "2015-01-05" & Login == "2015-01-06" & Login == "2015-01-07", "Yes", "No")
        )
```

I want to be able to capture Three_day, Four_day, etc. But I know my code isn't correct... Maybe my whole approach is wrong? Any help would be appreciated but I'd like to stick with dplyr on figuring it out.

Comment: I guess you need to use `lag/lead` to create a new column

Comment: logging in the day after the fixed day 0.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this helps

```
library(dplyr)
library(reshape2)
df1 <- df %>% 
         group_by(User) %>% 
         mutate(indx= as.numeric(as.Date(lead(Login))-
                        as.Date(Login)[1])) %>% 
         filter(!is.na(indx))
d1 <- dcast(df1, User~indx)
d1[-1] <- `dim<-`(c( 'No', 'Yes')[(!is.na(d1[-1]))+1], dim(d1[-1]))
colnames(d1)[-1] <- paste('day', colnames(d1)[-1], sep="_")
d1
#   User day_1 day_2 day_5
#1    A   Yes   Yes    No
#2    B    No   Yes    No
#3    C    No    No   Yes
```